# Format and Import to QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, json

I have a parcel which I would like to load into QGIS. The county's GIS website is not a standard Arc REST format, so I am struggling with the formatting. It uses "mapgeo" and I am not sure how to import the data into QGIS.

Here is the link https://carrollcova.mapgeo.io/api/ui/datasets/properties/77-A-64

I *think* this is a .json format, but I cannot figure out how to import it to QGIS.

I have tried converting it into a .csv file, but I do not know which fields I should use for lat/long since there are so many options.

I have tried using https://ogre.adc4gis.com/ to convert it to a geojson, but it could not read the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed was not a standard geojson.
However the coordinates and attributes were easy to reconfigure to geojson format.

you can use this short script to load this data into qgis or save to a file if you enter a valid output folder on your machine.

```
from requests import get
import json

url = 'https://carrollcova.mapgeo.io/api/ui/datasets/properties/77-A-64'
r = get(url)
obj = r.json()

base_object = {'type': "FeatureCollection",'features':[]}
for g in obj["geometries"]:
    feature = {'type' : 'Feature','properties' : {},'geometry' : {}}
    feature['geometry'] = g['geometry']
    feature['properties'] = obj["data"]
    base_object["features"].append(feature)

# Load to QGIS or comment out
iface.addVectorLayer(json.dumps(base_object), 'New Layer', 'ogr')


# Save to the path specified by filename
filname = "path/save/this.geosjon"
with open(filname, 'w') as file:
     file.write(json.dumps(base_object))
```

[image: what came up when loading this data]